# SQL select across multiple tables with max dates in each joined table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, max

I have an Oracle 11 SQL query where I'm pulling data from 4 tables all joined by an ID. The 3 tables joined to the first each have an ACTIVE_IND value that needs to be 'Y' and an effective date (EFF_DATE) and I need the record with maximum effective date from each.

I've got a query that works here, but would like to know if there is a more optimal/effective/efficient way of writing it as it seems a bit slow.  What I'm currently using looks something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.TABLE1_ID,
                A.TABLE1_COL1,
                B.TABLE2_COL2,
                C.TABLE3_COL3,
                D.TABLE4_COL4
FROM TABLE1 A,
     TABLE2 B,
     TABLE3 C,
     TABLE4 D
WHERE B.TABLE2_ID = A.TABLE1_ID
  AND B.TABLE2_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y'
  AND B.TABLE2_EFF_DATE =
    (SELECT MAX (B2.TABLE2_EFF_DATE)
     FROM TABLE2 B2
     WHERE B2.TABLE2_ID = B.TABLE2_ID
       AND B2.TABLE2_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y')
  AND C.TABLE3_ID = A.TABLE1_ID
  AND C.TABLE3_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y'
  AND C.TABLE3_EFF_DATE =
    (SELECT MAX (C2.TABLE3_EFF_DATE)
     FROM TABLE3 C2
     WHERE C2.TABLE3_ID = C.TABLE3_ID
       AND C2.TABLE3_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y')
  AND D.TABLE4_ID = A.TABLE1_ID
  AND D.TABLE4_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y'
  AND D.TABLE4_EFF_DATE =
    (SELECT MAX (D2.TABLE4_EFF_DATE)
     FROM TABLE4 D2
     WHERE D2.TABLE4_ID = D.TABLE4_ID
       AND D2.TABLE4_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y')
ORDER BY A.TABLE1_ID;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.TABLE1_ID,
                A.TABLE1_COL1,
                B.TABLE2_COL2,
                C.TABLE3_COL3,
                D.TABLE4_COL4
FROM TABLE1 A
JOIN (SELECT T2.*, 
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE2_ID ORDER BY TABLE2_EFF_DATE DESC) RN
      FROM TABLE2 T2
      WHERE TABLE2_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y') B ON B.TABLE2_ID = A.TABLE1_ID AND B.RN=1
JOIN (SELECT T3.*, 
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE3_ID ORDER BY TABLE3_EFF_DATE DESC) RN
      FROM TABLE3 T3
      WHERE TABLE3_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y') C ON C.TABLE3_ID = A.TABLE1_ID AND C.RN=1
JOIN (SELECT T4.*, 
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE4_ID ORDER BY TABLE4_EFF_DATE DESC) RN
      FROM TABLE4 T4
      WHERE TABLE4_ACTIVE_IND = 'Y') D ON D.TABLE4_ID = A.TABLE1_ID AND D.RN=1
ORDER BY A.TABLE1_ID;
```

Comment: Thanks Mark.  Seems to work once I adjusted the 3 RN labels to be unique. I initial got a `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined` error.

Comment: Oops, seems I just missed the qualifiers, e.g. "B.RN=1".

Comment: @Brandon: Originally, I forgot to make the RN labels unique - about half an hour later I noticed my oversight and fixed it.